# How can I run summary statistics across 2 dataframe columns that aren't factors?

Tags: r

A bit of background:

I've got a data frame with ~10k rows and 5 columns, which I've imported from a SQL database. One of these columns houses a URL, and the rest include a few other variables, a mix of integers and characters. Here's an example of the table, with the class of each column in brackets:

```
     URL(char)   A(char)   B(char)   C(int)   
1    http://      ab         gh        11       
2    http://      cd         ij        14      
3    http://      ef         kl        11      
...
```

When reading the table in the SQL server into R, I didn't use stringsAsFactors because part of what I need to do is break apart the URL to extract several strings from it:

1. **a city name**
2. **an occupation type**
3. **the salary**

That's cool, I'm down to regex and grep the stuff I need out of the URLs, and make a new column for each. Here's an example of how I've done it for the city.

```
dF$city= str_extract_all(string = dF$source_url, pattern = "newyork|los_angeles|chicago|houston|philadelphia|phoenix|san_antonio|san_diego|dallas")
```

Once I've finished, the data frame looks like this:

```
     URL(char)   A(char)   B(char)   C(int)   City(list)   Occupation(list)   Salary(list) 
1    http://      ab         gh        11       NY            programmer          90
2    http://      cd         ij        14       SF            ditch digger        85
3    http://      ef         kl        11       LA            programmer          88
...
```

Cool. Now I'm feeling good, and decide to run the summary statistics. Specifically, I want to find the mean wages for every occupation I've got on the list (there's about a dozen different types, all with uniform spelling). Since I'm still getting the hang of loops in R, I've been banging my head against the wall here — how would I figure out how, for each city and occupation, to get the mean salary?

Note that I'm trying to do all this under the condition that stringsAsFactors is set to false so that I can regex/grep the necessary portion of the URL.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version, where the dataframe has only 'A', 'City', 'Occupation', and 'Salary'. There are simple numbers for Salary so you can quickly visually check that the results are accurate.

It's actually pretty simple (fingers crossed). You just have to use `unlist`.

Another thing, I wouldn't get too hung up on using factors, or feel like you *must* use them. In this case, factors are not necessary at all.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
library('dplyr')
library('stringr')
```

The `source_URL` should hopefully be something like what you have:

```
source_URL <- c('NYblahditch digger10', 'NYhassomeprogrammermaking20', 'IheartNYditch digger30', 'NYnotNJprogrammer40', 'SFsmellsditch diggers50', '60programmerSF', 'ditch diggerInSFmakes70kayear', 'SFarewedoneyet80programmer')
```

Now we create the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c('ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl', 'mn', 'op'))
df$City <- unlist(str_extract_all(string = source_URL, pattern = "NY|SF"))           
df$Occupation <- unlist(str_extract_all(string = source_URL, pattern = "ditch digger|programmer"))
df$Salary <- as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(string = source_URL, pattern = '10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80')))
```

Check to make sure the dataframe looks like how you need it to be to continue:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':  8 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ A         : Factor w/ 8 levels "ab","cd","ef",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
$ City      : chr  "NY" "NY" "NY" "NY" ...
$ Occupation: chr  "ditch digger" "programmer" "ditch digger" "programmer" ...
$ Salary    : num  10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Now put `dplyr` to use:

```
df1 <- group_by(df, City, Occupation) %>%
   summarise(Mean_Wage = mean(Salary))
```

..and here we have the result:

```
> df1
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: City

City   Occupation Mean_Wage
1   NY ditch digger  20
2   NY   programmer  30
3   SF ditch digger  60
4   SF   programmer  70
```